# What is the proper way of determining if a limit does not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to show that the $\lim_\limits{x\to-2} \frac{4x^2}{x+2}$ does not exist. My current method is to simply graph it using Desmos and seeing that $\lim_\limits{x\to-2^-} \frac{4x^2}{x+2} = -\infty$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to-2^+} \frac{4x^2}{x+2} = +\infty$, but I was wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: The fact that right and left limits are different, together with the uniqueness theorem of limits imply that the limit cannot exist (to note: it is not always true that limits are unique; in general topological spaces, there may even be infinitely many different limits. Here, I'm referring to the uniqueness theorem for reals under the usual topology).

Comment: If $|x-(-2)| < \epsilon < 1$ then $-x < -2-\epsilon < -1$, so $|x| > 1$.  Then $|4x^2 /(x+2)| > 4 / \epsilon$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose the limit did exist i.e.,

$$\lim_{x\to-2}{4x^2\over x+2}=L$$

for some real number $L$. Then

$$\lim_{x\to-2}\left({4x^2\over x+2}-L \right)=0$$

in which case

$$\lim_{x\to-2}(x+2)\lim_{x\to2}\left({4x^2\over x+2}-L \right)=0\cdot0=0$$

as well.

But by the usual algebra for products and sums of limits that exist, we have

$$\lim_{x\to-2}(x+2)\lim_{x\to2}\left({4x^2\over x+2}-L \right)=\lim_{x\to-2}\left(4x^2-(x+2)L \right)=4\lim_{x\to-2}x^2-L\lim_{x\to-2}(x+2)\\=4\cdot4-L\cdot0=16$$

which is a contradiction, since $16\not=0$. So the limit does not exist.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There's a proof using $\epsilon - \delta$ methodology, but if it's too hard, rewrite the numerator as $4((x+2)^2 - 2 \times 2 (x+2) + 4)$, two first terms cancel out (+only convergent terms or constants left), so the third expression is of the form (set $x+2 = t$)
$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{t}
$$
Observe that for $t >0 $ the function increases unbounded as $t \to 0^{+}$ and decreases unbounded as $t \to 0 ^{-}$, e.g. by taking derivatives and showing they are either always positive or always negative. Therefore at $t=0$ there's a discontinuity that can't be removed. Conclude that the function doesn't exist at $t=0$.

EDIT: for the first step, consider (since $x^2 = (x+2-2)^2 = (x+2)^2  - 2 \times 2 \times (x+2)+4$
$$
\frac{4 x^2}{x+2}  = \frac{4((x+2)^2 - 2 \times 2 (x+2) + 4)}{x+2} = 4(x+2) - 4 + \frac{4}{x+2}
$$
The first two terms converge, and the third is $\frac{1}{t}$ if you set $t=x+2$

Comment: I'm not making the logical jump when you say "two first terms cancel out (+only convergent terms or constants left), so the third expression is of the form (set +2=)". Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @doctopus: see the edit

Answer (score 1):

Numerator is positive for the right Hand limit and left hand limit so u just have to check for denominator for the left hand limit it is negative so the limit is -infinite and denominator of left hand limit is positive so the limit is +infinite

Answer (score 1):

How about this: 
Let's divide the numerator and denominator by $x^2$ (because..why not?)
We'll end up in : 
$$\lim_{x\to -2^+}\dfrac{4}{\frac1x+\frac{2}
{x^2}}$$
Now let's modify this a little:
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{4}{\frac{1}{-2+h}+\frac{2}{(-2+h)^2}}$$
Now as $h\to 0$ the limit is clearly tending to $\infty$

Comment: This is all that you need, to prove that the limit will not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=-2+\delta$. Then

$$f(x)=\frac{4(-2+\delta)^2}\delta=\frac{16}\delta-16+\delta$$ and this value is unbounded, i.e. for any $M$ you can find $\delta>0$ such that

$$f(x)>M$$ or $\delta<0$ such that $$f(x)<M.$$